# Display images in PyroCMS depending on its {{ name }}-tag

Tags: loops, conditional-statements, pyrocms, strpos, pyrocms-lex

I need to display some images from a folder depending on its `{{ name }}`.

The names of my files look like this:

- foo.jpg
- foo_blur.jpg
- bar.png
- bar_blur.png

Now I need to do something with the *blurred*-image. This is what I tried, but no success:

```
{{ files:listing folder='1' }}
    {{ if { helper:strpos haystack='[[ name ]]' needle='_blur' } }}
        {{ files:image id='{{ id }}' }}
    {{ endif }}
{{ /files:listing }}
```

Currently it just does nothing. It seems that the `strpos` returns allways `false`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by myself, thanks to Leon Stafford:

Just remove the brackets `[[ ]]` **and** its surrounding `quotes`

```
{{ files:listing folder='1' }}
    {{ if { helper:strpos haystack=name needle='_blur' } }}
        {{ files:image id='{{ id }}' }}
    {{ endif }}
{{ /files:listing }}
```

Comment: no thanks to me, my solution was incorrect. but glad you got it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same curly braces for the `name` variable as you are for the `id`:

```
{{ files:listing folder='1' }}
    {{ if { helper:strpos haystack='{{ name }}' needle='_blur' } }}
        {{ files:image id='{{ id }}' }}
    {{ endif }}
{{ /files:listing }}
```

Comment: Tried already, this results in and parsing-error: `You have a syntax error in your Lex tags.`